# Avoid duplication of style on partial postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I used a partial postback in my ASPX pages. In some of the elements, I specify a css for styling, to mark whether the element is mandatory to fill in. Initially, without putting anything, when I do a partial postback, the styling inside my updatepanel is gone. So I added the code below to add back the lost styling.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        $(".Mandatory").append('&nbsp&nbsp<span style="color:red;">*</span>');
    }
}
```

The problem is that, if the element is outside my update panel, it will have the `*` sign duplicated.

Is there any way to resolve this? I.e. how to check if the certain class already have `<span style="color:red;">*</span>` so that I do not add the style twice?

Comment: You can restrict your selector to only select elements within your updatepanel. For example: $(".Mandatory #updatepanel")

Comment: Ok I managed to do that by doing like your comment, just that I put the #updatepanel first and then the class, so it looks like this:
`$("#<%=updtPnl.ClientID %> .Mandatory").append('&nbsp&nbsp<span style="color:red;">*</span>');`
If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your selector to only select elements within your updatepanel. For example:

```
$("#updatepanel .Mandatory").append('&nbsp&nbsp<span style="color:red;">*</span>');
```